# ERR (3): Notice: Array to string conversion /lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php on line 2976

Tags: magento-1.9, core, error-log

I'm getting this
ERR (3): Notice: Array to string conversion /lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php on line 2976
in my system.log
I observed it on Magento 1.9.0.1 and after upgrade to 1.9.1.0

How to fix it or - is this a big problem ?

Thanks
T

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(This should probably be a comment to your question.)

You are trying to put an array in a column that expects longtext. If you can reproduce this notice and thus know what is saved during that request, you will probably see it saved the text 'Array' somewhere, instead of the expected piece of text.

If you know that, you can probably figure out how it got there as an array (maybe from a form with name "something[]", something would be mapped to an array in that case).